# Blender 2.80+ Game Engine Replacement with Python

Tags: python, game-engine

I was mostly using Blender for simulations and interactive visualizations controlled by Python. Now 2.80 **REMOVED** the Blender Game Engine with no replacement!!!!

Really not cool to remove something that was there for decades with no replacement! I have checked the external game engines but this is not the same - I need to export/import and write in some funny languages while I had everything at hand in Blender :-(

Blender became **just** a 3D modelling tool :-(

Is there any way so I can perform a live real-time visualizations that are Python controlled in new Blender 2.80+ ? I don't really need physics (but the collisions would be nice to have).

Any hints welcome.. or I need to stick to 2.79.

Comment: I think BGE was removed because nobody was maintaining it and other game engines were more accessible with better features.  Other engines do support python (UE4, Panda3D etc.) but will have a different API, which will have a small learning curve.  You can always get [older versions of blender](https://download.blender.org/release/), what sort of interaction do you need?

Comment: so far i am trying to build UPBGE on my FreeBSD box it is a Blender fork with BGE still active: https://upbge.org/

Comment: I forgot about that.  Yes that's a way to go, but building on FreeBSD is going to be fun!

Comment: UPBGE is now working on FreeBSD. However it does not run all Blender 2.79- applications / scripts correctly so it's NOT 1:1 replacement. I need to stay with 1.79 :-(

Comment: you might want to have a look at Armory 3D too

Answer (score 0):

At some point in time, an "interactive mode" was in discussion/announced. But it seems this was dropped, according to a statemen at Blender Conference 2019. You can check some discussion at Blenderartists:

https://blenderartists.org/t/any-news-on-blender-2-8-interactive-mode/1178594

Comment: Thank you. Did put my two cents over there. Blender lost my Respect and Trust. New team just removed something that was there for 25 years with no replacement no alternative and it looks there is even no plan for alternative. SO LAME! :-(